# Why is fscanf changing values of structure without explicitly being told to?

Tags: c, file-io, data-structures, scanf

I am trying to read a text file into a structure in c, but on the last iteration of my `fscanf()` loop, it changes both the numbers and text stored in the first and some of the second parts of my structure.

Debugging has revealed that this behaviour is caused by the `while` `fscanf()` loop. Although changing the size of the strings input prevented the numbers being changed, the string on the first line `PMs.Party[0]` still changed from = **Labour** to **r**. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

void PartyPwr( int Runs, int Time[12], char Prty[12][15]);

struct Data
{
    char *Name[12][15];
    int StrtMnth[12];
    int StrtYr[12];
    int EndMnth[12];
    int EndYr[12];
    char Party[12][15]; // if this is 13 20 it runs without numbers changing.
    int TimePwr[12];
};

int main(void)
{
    int Max=0;
    int i=0;
    FILE *PriMins;
    struct Data PMs;
    if ((PriMins=fopen("PM.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: PM.txt cannot be read.");
        system("pause");
        return(1);
    }
    while(fscanf(PriMins, "%s %d %d %d %d %s", &PMs.Name[Max], &PMs.StrtMnth[Max], &PMs.StrtYr[Max], &PMs.EndMnth[Max], &PMs.EndYr[Max], &PMs.Party[Max]) > 0)
    {
        PMs.TimePwr[Max]=((PMs.EndMnth[Max] +(PMs.EndYr[Max]*12)) - (PMs.StrtMnth[Max] + (PMs.StrtYr[Max]*12)));
        printf("%s %d Total term %d\n",PMs.Name[Max], PMs.EndMnth[Max],PMs.TimePwr[Max]);
        printf("Max val, %d bug check %d, %d, Party %s\n",Max, PMs.TimePwr[0], PMs.TimePwr[1], PMs.Party[0]);
        Max++;
    }
    //PartyPwr(Max, PMs.TimePwr, PMs.Party);
    //printf("%d, %d", PMs.TimePwr[0], PMs.TimePwr[1]);
    fclose(PriMins);
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}

void PartyPwr( int Runs , int Time[12], char Prty[12][15])
    int i=0;
    int LabPwr=0;
    int ConPwr=0;
    for (i=0;i<Runs;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", Prty[i]);
        if (strcmp(Prty[i],"Labour")==0)
        {
            LabPwr=(LabPwr+Time[i]);
        }
        if (strcmp(Prty[i],"Conservative")==0)
        {
            ConPwr=(ConPwr+Time[i]);
        }
        if ((strcmp(Prty[i],"Conservative")!=0) && (strcmp(Prty[i],"Labour")!=0))
        {
            printf("An invalid party was present in the list.");
        }

    }
    printf ("Total Labour time in power: %d\nTotal Conservative time in power: %d\n", LabPwr, ConPwr);
}
```

This is the text file for the programme.

```
Attlee        7   1945  10  1951 Labour
Churchill    11   1951   5  1955 Conservative
Eden          6   1955  12  1956 Conservative
Macmillan     1   1957  10  1963 Conservative
Douglas-Home 11   1963  10  1964 Conservative
Wilson       11   1964   5  1970 Labour
Heath         6   1970   2  1974 Conservative
Wilson        3   1974   3  1976 Labour
Callaghan     4   1976   4  1979 Labour
Thatcher      5   1979  11  1990 Conservative
Major        12   1990   4  1997 Conservative
Blair         5   1997   6  2007 Labour
Brown         6   2007   5  2010 Labour
```

EDIT: I've just discovered if the size of every variable in Data is increased by one, the code runs without any of the issues. I assume this is some kind of overflow?

EDIT 2: Specifically if `EndYr` is **[13]** not **[12]** the problem is eliminated.

Comment: do you really want `char *Name[12][15];`? or it should  be `char Name[12][15];`

Comment: Good point actually I think that was left over from when I was going to dynamically assign length.

Comment: If I increase the size of all my variables by 1 the code runs fine. So I've fixed it in a sense but have no idea WHY.

Comment: Your text file seems to have 13 rows, but all your arrays only have 12 elements. That is very much like overflow.

Comment: I thought we started at 0 though, 0 through 12 is 13 values.

Comment: Array with 12 elements only goes from 0 to 11.

Comment: i don't think your edit2 should work.You should increase all of them

Comment: Another improvement" `while(fscanf(PriMins, "%14s %d %d %d %d %14s", ... ) == 6)`  Limit data read into strings and compare against 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading 13 records from the file and have space to store only 12 of them as all you data items are of size 12.If you increase the size by 1 there is enough room for all 13 records

```
struct Data
{
   char Name[13][15];
   int StrtMnth[13];
   int StrtYr[13];
   int EndMnth[13];
   int EndYr[13];
   char Party[13][15]; 
   int TimePwr[13];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The word `Conservative` is 12 characters, but you must account for the null char '\0' at the end of every C string.

That is why your code works when you use 13 chars array for the Party field.

**What you should do**

Specify the maximum length of the Party field in the scanf format specifier. For example, if you keep 12 chars array for the party field:

```
fscanf(PriMins, "%s %d %d %d %d %11s", &PMs.Name[Max], &PMs.StrtMnth[Max], &PMs.StrtYr[Max], &PMs.EndMnth[Max], &PMs.EndYr[Max], &PMs.Party[Max])
```